# Fast computation/estimation of a full-rank linear system

Tags: r, regression, matlab, algorithms, linear-algebra

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/fast-computation-estimation-of-a-low-rank-linear-system).

I have two full rank matrices $A_1,A_2$ each 
of dimension $p \times p$ and a p vector $y$.

These matrices are closely related in the sense that 
matrix  $A_2$ has $p-1$ row in common with matrix $A_1$.

Now, I'm interested in the vector $\beta_2$,
 where $\beta_2=(A_2'A_2)^{-1}(A_2'y)$.

My question: Is there is a fast way to get 
$\beta_2|(\beta_1,A_1,A_2,y)$ in R/matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I largely agree with what @DikranMarsupial said, it is typically a bad idea to form $A' A$ since it squares the condition number of $A$. It is more stable to recognize that changing the $i$th row of $A$ from $a'$ to $\hat a'$ is equivalent to perform the rank-one update $\hat A = A + e_i (\hat a-a)'$, where $e_i$ is a [standard basis vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis).

Thus, given a QR decomposition of $A$, the QR decomposition of $\hat A$ can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ work using, for example, [MATLAB's qrupdate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/qrupdate.html).

Roughly speaking, this approach should yield twice as many digits of accuracy as an approach which explicitly forms $A' A$.

Comment: > would you know of any implementation of QR updates in R? [there are a couple implementations of chol-update).

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I've never even used R, but this question was linked from your SciComp question. I was about to answer your question there, but you deleted it.

Comment: Jack Poulson:> i moved it to stakeoverflow ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659412/efficient-use-of-choleski-decomposition-in-r ). Im not sure it belongs to SciComp because im not sure the problem i have is a theoretical one (it could be due to me not using the right R functions). You are most welcome to answer it there

Comment: Answered there as well.

Comment: +1 for QR, I am to used to dealing with kernel methods, where you start with a kernel matrix, which is a covariance matrix in an implicit feature space.  Sometimes I forget people make linear models as well ;o)  P.S. ISTR that Morven Gentleman (?) published a nice paper on an incremental/decremental QR for linear regression, which would be ideal for this (title was something to do with Givens rotations without square roots?).

Answer (score 2):

Changing a row of $A$ will give a rank-1 update of $A'A$, recomputing the inverse of a matrix following a rank-1 update can be achieved using the [Sherman-Woodbury-Morrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) formula.  However this is numerically unstable, so it is better to perform the computation using a cholesky decomposition instead, which can be updated in a similar, but more numerically stable manner.  IIRC MATLAB has some commands built in for this, but I can't remember the names ('lookfor cholesky' ought to find them).  See also Matthias Seeger's software for [Updating the Cholesky Decomposition for Low Rank Modifications](http://lapmal.epfl.ch/software/index.shtml).  Matthias is a very bright guy, I suspect this is probably the best approach.

UPDATE - The command is cholupdate:

R1 = cholupdate(R,x) where R = chol(A) is the original Cholesky factorization of A, returns the upper triangular Cholesky factor of A + x*x', where x is a column vector of appropriate length. cholupdate uses only the diagonal and upper triangle of R. The lower triangle of R is ignored

so R1 = chol(A1'*A1); followed by R2=cholupdate(R1,x); ought to do the trick, where x is the differrence between the row of A1 that is replaced to get A2 and the new row in A2.  I can't check as I don't have access to MATLAB at home, but it will be something of that nature.  You can then get $\beta_2$ by the standard method for regression with Cholesy decomposition.

Comment: I've updated the post, I think it os what you want, but I can't check it until I go bak to work on the 3rd.

Comment: note update chol(A1'*A1) rather than just chol(A1).

Comment: I think you will find that this method yields a rank-2 update of A' A.